# Using renderToNodeStream with react-rails / webpacker

Tags: styled-components, webpacker, react-rails, execjs, react-dom-server

I'm working on an app using [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) / [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/), with a rails server and React frontend. On top of this, we are also using [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) and have overwritten the existing *ReactRailsUJS.serverRender* method in the *app/javascript/packs/server_rendering.js* file to account for styled components as the following (see https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/issues/864#issue-291728172 for more info):

```
// server_rendering.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';

const componentRequireContext = require.context('components', true);
const ReactRailsUJS = require('react_ujs');
ReactRailsUJS.useContext(componentRequireContext);

ReactRailsUJS.serverRender = function(renderFunction, componentName, props) {
  const ComponentConstructor = this.getConstructor(componentName);
  const stylesheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
  const wrappedElement = stylesheet.collectStyles(
    <ComponentConstructor {...props} />
  );
  const text = ReactDOMServer[renderFunction](wrappedElement);

  // prepend the style tags to the component HTML
  return `${stylesheet.getStyleTags()}${text}`;
}
```

This all works well, since the *renderFunction* param passed as the first argument of the *ReactRailsUJS.serverRender* function is [react-dom/server's renderToString method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring). However, we would like to update the application to use the [renderToNodeStream](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertonodestream) method for rendering our react components, which is what brings me to this discussion.

I was wondering if there is anyone out there with some more in depth knowledge of how these libraries work at a more core level to help me figure out how we might be able to use renderToNodeStream, given our application setup.

Any advice / direction is appreciated, and I can provide additional information if necessary. Thank you for the consideration and help!